# File explorer broken in latest Windows 10

Tags: windowsiot

I can see my app saves and loads my data to/from ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder just fine.

However, when I open web interface, click Apps, File explorer, LocalAppData, my app ID, I see “This folder has no data associated with it”. For all preinstalled apps, IoTCoreDefaultApp, IoTUAPOOBE, IoTOnboardingTask, ZWave Adapter Headless Host, web interface says the same.

Couple months ago it worked fine, probably broken with a windows update (I’m now running v.10.0.15063.297).

Any workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use [Windows file sharing](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/windowsfilesharing) to access app files like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked. Here's the mount command I use to access that location:
Net use I: \\192.168.0.20\C$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages **** /user:Administrator /persistent:no

Comment: Thanks! I was not able to use the File Explorer in the Windows Device Portal (via the browser). I could indeed only use \\thedevice\c$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\xxx\LocalState