# Saved files on Raspberry Pi are not visible in Device Portal

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am saving log files on a Raspberry Pi using this method to get the save path:

```
private static string GetFullFilePath(ISettingsReader settingsReader)
{
   StorageFolder appLocalFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
   var logFilPath = appLocalFolder.Path + settingsReader.LogFileName;
   return logFilPath;
}
```

The files are saved at this location on the RPi:

c$\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\**MyApp_ktn1kqb2ndh66**\LocalState\Logs

If I open Device Portal - File Explorer I see a slightly different name for my app: User Folders\LocalAppData\**MyApp_1.0.0.0_arm_ktn1kqb2ndh66**

There are no files under that link.

If I search for the folder name on the RPi I can find it under c$\Data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages

Where do I have to save the files so that they are available on the Device Portal?

Comment: This issue looks like come with new Windows iot core version(v.10.0.15063.297), see [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295992/file-explorer-broken-in-latest-windows-10) for a workaround.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I knew about the workaround, but I will need something that I can use when the RPi will be out on the field.

Comment: What's the meaning of **being out on the field**?